# Removed Atom from Applications. How to remove `atom` command from terminal?

Tags: terminal

Recently I started using Microsoft Visual Studio Code instead of Atom. So I deleted Atom from the Applications folder. However, I can still autocomplete the `atom` command in terminal. And searching for it with `where atom` doesn't give any results (`command not found`).

I tried looking for it in `~/.zshrc` but nothing there points to `atom` either.

Any idea where I can remove that command?

Using iTerm2 and om-my-zsh.

**Update**

- The output of `type -a atom` is `atom not found`.
- This is after a reboot of my machine; the terminal has been refreshed.
- The output of `alias` does not contain `atom`.
- I misremembered the `which` command and used `where` instead. That was my issue. Accepted the answer stating this.

Comment: Please share the output of running `type -a atom` in Terminal.

Comment: @NimeshNeema `atom not found`. updated the question too.

Comment: Have you tries a new terminal session?

Comment: @Mark Yes :) Updated the question.

Comment: i'm not famiilar with the oh-my-zsh shell but in the bash shell there  is a file named .bash_profile that would have an atom alias set. Have you tried typing 'which atom' in the terminal?  or type 'alias' or some command to give you a list of aliases..

Comment: @jmh I mention the result of `which atom` in the question. Thanks for the advice, but I checked `.zshrc`, which is oh-my-zsh's .bash_profile equivalent. No aliases have been set to `atom`.

Comment: Apologies @jmh, I confused `where` with `which`. Your comment would've helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where atom`will result in `command not found`, true, but because the `where` command is not found; when using bash. A zsh error would have issued "`atom not found`"

Try `which atom` to get the result of `/usr/local/bin/atom` in bash.

That means you just need to `rm /usr/local/bin/atom` to get rid of that command.

(Atom.app install also `apm`, so be sure to remove that as well.)

Comment: `where` is a `zsh` builtin command.

Comment: @fd0 That's true. But to me it looked as if bash was used to issue that command. zsh error would have looked different